# ClearType: Change color with a shader (Windows)

Tags: windows, fonts, shader, alpha-transparency

I let Windows draw a few **white** glyphs with transparent background into a device context with a bitmap and to my astonishment, I saw this:[image]

I have 1 question:

How should I treat the RGB channels inside a shader to produce glyph of a certain color with this colorful contrast?

Comment: Microsoft [ClearType](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ClearType) font smoothing. Basically, this is what makes text look decent in Windows. I can immediately spot a label in a dialog box drawn using MS Sans Serif, because the lack of font smoothing makes it look horrible (back to the 90s).

Comment: Thank you! I've edited the question since now I know what the effect is caused by... I'm looking at [this](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/research/publication/displaced-filtering-for-patterned-displays/) now. Do you think that implementing the shader would be easy? Maybe I could turn ClearType off when changing colors dynamically. And use it otherwise...